# Delimiter for Splitting each character of a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to split two-character strings into two separate columns for each character in a pandas data.frame, but I've been struggling to find a way to perform the operation on the column without having to iterate through each row.

My starting data.frame looks something like this:

```
  Initial
0      PT
1      XT
2      ZT
```

And I'm hoping to split the 'Initial' column into two separate columns containing each character like this:

```
  S1 S2
0  P  T
1  X  T
2  Z  T
```

I've used the `split()` function, and I've tried to find a proper delimiter to supply it which would split every character, but I'm at a loss so far. Is there a good way to do this without needing to iterate over each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html):

```
df["S1"] = df["Initial"].str.slice(0, 1)
df["S2"] = df["Initial"].str.slice(1, 2)
```

Which gives:

```
  Initial S1 S2
0      PT  P  T
1      XT  X  T
2      ZT  Z  T
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), using a regex to match the position between the two characters (for example, `(?<=^.)`, a lookbehind for a single character after start of string) and `expand=True`:

```py
df[['S1', 'S2']] = df['Initial'].str.split(r'(?<=^.)', expand=True, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
  Initial S1 S2
0      PT  P  T
1      XT  X  T
2      ZT  Z  T
```

You can the [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pandas.DataFrame.drop) the `Initial` column if it is no longer required:

```py
df.drop('Initial', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
  S1 S2
0  P  T
1  X  T
2  Z  T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```py
df[["S1", "S2"]] = df.Initial.str.extract(r"(.)(.)")
df.drop("Initial", axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

---

```
  S1 S2
0  P  T
1  X  T
2  Z  T
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting all characters as new columns using conversion to list:

```
out = (
 pd.DataFrame(df['Initial'].apply(list).tolist(),
              index=df.index)
   .rename(columns=lambda x: f'S{x+1}')
   .fillna('') # optional, only if non-even input
 )
```

Output:

```
  S1 S2
0  P  T
1  X  T
2  Z  T
```

On a non-even input:

```
# input
  Initial
0      PT
1      XT
2      ZT
3     ABC

# output

  S1 S2 S3
0  P  T   
1  X  T   
2  Z  T   
3  A  B  C
```

Comment: TIL - you can use a function in `rename`. That's quite cool.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about pandas, but `list(text)` will create a list of all characters in a string

Then you could try to create a dataframe over a list of lists.